# How to change/create password keyring

Tags: 10.10, password, keyrings

when I try to remote desktop to the server from another ubuntu machine using the remote desktop viewer, it asks me to enter the password, which I do, then the viewer pane just goes black. When I come back and look at my server it is saying that the password keyring no longer matches the password used to login to the machine please reenter the password...and when I type in the password it doesnt take it, it just keeps popping back up saying the same message over and over.

I found a thread explaining to go to System-->Preferences-->Passwords & Encryptions and right click on the keyring and click Set as Default.

I did that and the problem persists...I tried changing the password but it told me that my original password was incorrect (even though it is the password I use to login and provide root authentication when asked)

so I deleted the keyring in hopes of adding a new one but there is no place in gui to add a new one...so can I add a new one through command line?

if so - how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found what I was looking for within the passwords and keyrings section under preferences:
I totally missed the menu bar at the top with file, edit, blah blah blah.  Anyways, I went to file, new and created a new keyring.  After that I could connect perfectly fine with no issues.  So creating a new keyring (or changing the password) fixed my problem.

Comment: As a further note, once I created a new keyring with my login password, I set it as default (and deleted the old one, but that is strictly optional).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are looking for this dialog in *System -> Preferences -> Remote Desktop*

[image: VNC Password]

where you can define a password for remote desktop access (maximum 8 characters). Also avoid special characters to minimize authentification problems.